# save dataframes as csv in function silently instead of a through a list (iwalk?)

Tags: r, csv, lapply, purrr

I'm reading in very large files from an SQL database, doing some data processing and trying to save the final version as a `csv` file as I go silently. Most questions I've come across on this topic suggest saving my dataframes in a list first and then saving them individually like this, which works in this very small example:

```
library(tidyverse)
SQLlarge <- mtcars
SQLlarge2 <- mtcars
sql_fun <- function(x) {

  sql_large_filter <- SQLlarge %>% 
    filter(gear == {{x}})
  #other data processing

  sql_large_filter2 <- SQLlarge2 %>% 
    filter(gear == {{x}})
  #other data processing

  final <- sql_large_filter %>% 
    bind_rows(sql_large_filter2)
  final
}
sql_fun(3)
temp <- lapply(c(3, 4, 5), sql_fun)
names(temp) <- paste0("df_", 3:5)
lapply(1:length(temp), function(x) write_csv(temp[[x]], path = paste0("C:\\Users\\", names(temp[x]), ".csv")))
```

this works and creates 3 dfs called `df_3`, `df_4`, `df_5` but because my files are so big I dont want to save them in a large list first so I want save at the end of each iteration at the end of the function or save silently (`iwalk`?). Something like this:

```
sql_fun2 <- function(x) {

  sql_large_filter <- SQLlarge %>% 
    filter(gear == {{x}})
  #other data processing

  sql_large_filter2 <- SQLlarge2 %>% 
    filter(gear == {{x}})
  #other data processing

  final <- sql_large_filter %>% 
    bind_rows(sql_large_filter2)


  arg_name <- deparse(substitute(x)) # Get argument name
  var_name <- paste("df", arg_name, sep = "_") 
  #assign(var_name, final, env = .GlobalEnv) 

  write_csv(final, path = paste0("C:\\Users\\", var_name, ".csv")) 

  #OR iwalk?
  # lst(final) %>%
  #   iwalk(., function(df, name) {
  #     write_csv(df, sprintf("C:\\Users\\%s.csv", name))
  #   })

}
sql_fun(3)
#works df_3 created but when calling over 3:5: 

map(3:5, sql_fun2)
#returns only one df called "df_.x[[i]].csv"
```

This only returns one df called `df_.x[[i]].csv` so I'm not indexing correctly in my `write_csv` call within the function? The other option was to save it silently using `iwalk` so include the following within `sql_fun2`:

```
lst(final) %>%       #not sure how to rename final within dataframe first?
  iwalk(., function(df, name) {
    write_csv(df, sprintf("C:\\Users\\%s.csv", name))
  })
```

but I'm not sure how to assign a name to a dataframe that im not assigning to the global environment (typically we would rename the dataframe with `assign(var_name, final, env = .GlobalEnv)`.

Is this the correct approach? Any suggestions welcome.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your thinking and approach is correct. Change one line in the function to :

```
library(purrr)

sql_fun2 <- function(x) {
   #All other lines of the function as it is
   #Previous line
   #write_csv(final, path = paste0("C:\\Users\\", var_name, ".csv"))
   #New line
   write_csv(final, path = paste0("C:\\Users\\", x, ".csv")) 
}
```

and then call it with

```
purrr::map(3:5, sql_fun2)
```

---

The crux of the issue is how the arguments are passed to the function. The main point of confusion is `deparse(substitute(x))`. Check it's value :

```
sql_fun3 <- function(x) {
    deparse(substitute(x)) 
 }

map(3:5, sql_fun3)
#[[1]]
#[1] ".x[[i]]"

#[[2]]
#[1] ".x[[i]]"

#[[3]]
#[1] ".x[[i]]"
```

Since the same value is used in every iteration the previous csv get's overwritten and you are left with only one csv with latest data.  Now check what is `x`

```
sql_fun4 <- function(x) {
   x
 }

map(3:5, sql_fun4)
#[[1]]
#[1] 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 4

#[[3]]
#[1] 5
```

So this would give you unique csv for each iteration.

Comment: thank you, that works, would you know how the `iwalk` would look?

Comment: I don't think `iwalk` fits in here since you want to write the csv in function itself. You could use `imap`/`iwalk` with `sql_fun`.